# How to add MAPBOX_API to path(windows)

Tags: api, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, mapbox

someone told me add

MAPBOX_API_KEY = "(my api key)"

this to my path(environment variable) (windows 10) to solve my problem
but don't know how to do that

am i should use setx command?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please detail why you would do that?

In any case, this is how you can edit your environment variables (including the PATH variable):

- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.